# How to make text slide by only using css/html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a caption slide into a picture from the top once you mouse over it. Everything seems to work except for the fact that the text does not Slide. The animation happens instantly. Is there a way to make the text slide without coding jQuery? I'm not too familiar with `-webkit-transitions` but I ended up using a lot for this code.

HTML 1st Column of Grid:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <a href="#" class="darken">
    <h3 class="pictureCaption">Click Me!</h3>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="darken">
    <h3 class="pictureCaption">Click Me!</h3>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </a>
</div><!-- end col-md-4 -->
```

CSS:

```
/*-------------------------------
      Picture Gallery
---------------------------------*/
#pictureGallery .row .col-md-4 {
    text-align: center;
}

#pictureGallery .row .col-md-4 .darken {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#pictureGallery .row .col-md-4 .darken img {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

#pictureGallery .row .col-md-4 .darken:hover img {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

 .pictureCaption {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    color: transparent;
    transition: all 2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
}

#pictureGallery .row .col-md-4 .darken:hover .pictureCaption {
    color: white;
    top: 120px;
}
```

Thanks in advance! I'm a rookie.. but I've learned so much from this site! Any tips are appreciated!

I Made a JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Veetz/7ec7avrd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also made you an example, I'll explain:

Put the image you want in a div.
This div has an overflow:hidden;

After that, you also add some text inside this div, by using the  tag.(for example)
Set the margin of the text negative so it wont be visible inside the 'wrapper-div'.

Now, in CSS add an :hover for the image-wrapper div with an positive left margin.
By making use of CSS-transitions, the text will be "animated".

**Down here some example CSS:**

```
.image-wrapper{
    width:400px;
    height:439px;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:left 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:left 2s ease-in-out;
}

.image-wrapper img{
    width:100%;
}

.image-wrapper a{
    position:relative;
    font-size:24px;
    color:red;
    font-weight:600;
    left:-180px;
    bottom:60px;
    -webkit-transition:left 1s ease-in-out;
}

.image-wrapper:hover > a{
    left:120px;
}
```

Also, an [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/1zd06Lj7/1/) for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example i have just created, might assist

http://jsfiddle.net/jagmitg/qp67k62d/

Using list items not `DIV`

**EDIT:**

Added animation, slide from the left to right

http://jsfiddle.net/jagmitg/6ncoh1on/

Comment: hmm, i don't see the text sliding here .. I'm trying to make the text slide into the picture.. not just appear instantly. Thanks though.

Comment: ty i love that there are so many different ways to do things in programming